# Algorithms apparently off-topic: should we edit the help page?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, help-center

Our help page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:–

> If your question is about
>
> **Programming**, ask on Stack Overflow.  If the language
>   is statistically oriented (such as **R**,
>   **SAS**, **Stata**, **SPSS**,
>   etc.), then decide based on the nature of your question: if it needs
>   *statistical expertise* to understand or answer, ask it here;
>   if it's about an *algorithm*, routine *data processing*,
>   or details of the *language*, then please refer to the collection
>   of links to resources we maintain.

Can anyone tell the intent behind "if it's about an algorithm"? We don't regard questions about [Fisher scoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/205/17230) or [Hartigan–Wong](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/67380/17230) as off-topic. I think we should clarify that clause (or else remove it altogether).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe I originally formulated this clause.  The intended meaning of "algorithm" could more clearly be rendered as "implementation of an algorithm."  It was not meant to suggest that (statistically-related) algorithms are off-topic here.

Subject to further discussion, I would propose inserting the phrase "the implementation of" in the text.

Comment: Thanks, I've followed your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

A possible alternative would be "if it's about writing or implementing code,".  This distinguishes it from statistical algorithms altogether by using language specific to programming.

Comment: I think "the implementation of an algorithm" more clearly expresses what we want to get across: ["In computer science, an implementation is a realization of an algorithm as a program, software component, or other computer system through computer programming and deployment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementation).